# Error while querying ManyToOne data : Invalid derived query! No property id found

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a classes `Task` and `TaskAttribute`.

`Task` has

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
private Set<TaskAttribute> taskAttrs;
```

and `TaskAttribute` has

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="taskid")
private Task task;
```

Now everything is fine. I am using CRUDRepository for crud operations. I want to customize `getAll()` method to `getAll(taskId)` of TaskAttributeRepository. (Get all attributes only for one `TaskId`).

But while changing the definition of `getAll()` method in repository `interface`, I am getting error:

> Invalid derived query! No property id found for type Task! Traversed
>   path: TaskAttribute.task.

My TaskAttributeRepository looks like this:

```java
public interface TaskAttributeRepository extends CrudRepository<TaskAttribute, Long>{

    public Collection<TaskAttribute> getAllTasksAtrByTaskId(Long \*What should go here*\);

}
```

Comment: may be getAllTasksAtrByTaskid(Long taskid)

Comment: have been trying that only, but no luck. BTW i have extended with `JpaRepository` and used `@Query` to get it. But there should be a way to do it without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of the method worked for me.

Comment: @Query worked for me although still searching for proper reason

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it is just a method naming convention problem.

You can just change method name to `findByTaskTaskId(long taskId)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15478760)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes This does provide an answer to the question - just the wrong one. Flagging should rather not be used for checking is the answer correct - downvoting is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
public List<TaskAttribute> findByTask(Task task);
```

As your property has a `Task` type.